# Finding a Bin Similarity Matrix Between two histograms in Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram, similarity

H guys,

I'm looking to compare pairs of histograms in Matlab. I have done some research on the subject as I realize it is quite large. I have narrowed my options down to two methods:

1. Create GMMs for the data and compare via Kullback-Liebler using sampling
2. I found some algorithm for advanced chi-squared comparison between histograms. This algorithm takes two histograms, a bin similarity matrix and a normalization factor.

I have a very technical question: How do I retrieve this bin similarity matrix in Matlab? And how is the similarity between two individual bins defined? I can't seem to find a proper explanation for this anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: is this what you want?: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/pdist.html  you need stats toolbox though.  but you may find some stuff in community: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/index?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=pairwise+distance

Comment: Yea I saw the pdist. I don't think that outputs a distance matrix between two histograms, I think its more suited for euclidean distances between two sets of observations.

Comment: I gave a general answer on how to compare pairs of histograms. If you need a specific answer relating to a "bin similarity matrix", please include a reference for that. And by the way, it is Kullback–L*ei*bler.

Comment: Hi, if you check the links you will see that they both cover far more than just euclidean.  They will give you a pairwise distance matrix for many metrics.   'euclidean' 'seuclidean' 'cityblock' 'minkowski' 'chebychev' 'mahalanobis'  'cosine' 'correlation' 'spearman' 'hamming' 'jaccard'

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a "bin similarity matrix" and a search didn't turn up anything, so I'm just telling you here how I would compare histograms.

The standard approach in statistics is to use [Pearson's chi-squared statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Calculating_the_test-statistic). Note however that the associated hypothesis test assumes that one of the two distributions is known exactly, so you can't use it. You can still use the statistic as a measure of dissimilarity for two estimated distributions (histograms) though.

If you normalize the histogram it is an estimate of a probability distribution, which can therefore be just plugged into the [formula for Kullback–Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition).

Both chi-squared statistic and Kullback–Leibler divergence are not symmetrical in the two arguments. You can symmetrize both measures by applying it in both directions and then taking the mean. For KL divergence, this is a recognized [variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Symmetrised_divergence).

For all of this you have of course to make sure that the two histograms have been computed using the same definition of bins. Moreover, your results will strongly depend on how many bins you use.

Answer (score 0):

For me also, it was not clear in the paper how to calculate the bin similarity matrix.
However, the code of the paper that describes it is available here:

http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~ofirpele/QC/

There is a function called: sift_bin_similarity_function.m.
Therein the implementation of calculating the bin similarity.